# NavBar Button doesn't work when being clicked

Tags: swift, navbar

I'm trying to implement a button to my navbar which should call the function `addTap`.

Unfortunately though, when I click the `add` button in the simulator, nothing happens. I put a print statement in the `addTap` function but I doesn't get called, meaning the function never gets called.

Have any ideas?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var names : [String] = []
    
    let TableView = UITableView() // view
    
    var addButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(addTap))
    
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        setupComponents()
        setupTableView()
      }
    
    func setupComponents() {
        self.title = "Core Data"
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addButton
    }
    
    func setupTableView() {
        view.addSubview(TableView)
        TableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        TableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        TableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        TableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        TableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
      }
    
    @objc func addTap() {
        print("reached")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Friend", message: "Add the name of your friend", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Now", style: .default) { [unowned self] action in

              guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first, let nameToSave = textField.text else { return }

              self.names.append(nameToSave)
              self.TableView.reloadData()
          }

          let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)

          alert.addTextField()
          alert.addAction(saveAction)
          alert.addAction(cancelAction)
          present(alert, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Just be careful with your naming convention, your tableView variable shouldn't be called "TableView" you can tell already see the complier is confused as its the a different colour to the other variables. if this is a copy paste error ignore me, but this may cause you issues later on

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with the construction of your `UIBarButtonItem`. You are trying to access `self` before `self` exists.

If you construct it like this you will find that it works.

```
func setupComponents() {
    self.title = "Core Data"
    let addButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(addTap))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
}
```

Or if you need access to the button instance you can create the `UIBarButtonItem` [lazily](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-lazy-property-initialization) and replace the declaration in your class with the following:

```
lazy var addButton: UIBarButtonItem = {
    UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(addTap))
}()
```